# Passing Date field to google chart timeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to populate the Google chart timeline on my app using Ruby on Rails and the problem that I have is how to pass date to addrows([new Date()]]. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Below is the sample code

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
dataTable.addRows([
[ 'book id','book title', new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 10,1)],]]);
chart.draw(dataTable);
}
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="width: 1000px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way

```
dataTable.addRows([
[ 'book id','book title', <%= Time.now %>, <%= Time.now %>,]]);
```

More hint is here depending on your requirement --> [Ruby Time format](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm)